# sales Prediction per pharmacy and per products

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, forecasting

Hi Guys Hope you're doing well
I'm fairly new to machine learning topics. it'll be great if you could answer my question.
i'm working in a pharmaceutical distribution company and i want to do a research with a few products and a few pharmacies. i have 12 years of sales data and i wanted to know that can i predict sales for each pharmacy and each product? in other words i want to know for example next month pharmacy x will purchase n amount of product y, i want to do this with 1000 pharmacies and 50 products. is it possible with machine learning?
thank you guys in advance

I tried timer series but it doesn't allow me to use two dimensions(pharmacy and products).